# Creating multicast join for tcpdump captures

Tags: linux, shell-script, tcpdump, multicast

I want to write a linux shell script which will capture specific multicast traffic.  Specific as in, I want to create a pcap file that has all the traffic for one specific multicast group/port.

Here is the command line I am using to view traffic:

```
tcpdump -nnXs 0 -i eth1 udp port 22001 and dst 233.54.12.234
```

This works fine so long as I have a multicast subscription to that group already established.  For example, if I run this in another console:

```
mdump 233.54.12.234 22001 10.13.252.51
```

`tcpdump` will see packets.  If `mdump` is not running, `tcpdump` sees nothing.

Is there a standard linux-y way to establish these multicast joins before starting the captures?  I could use `mdump` to establish these joins, but that seems wasteful since `mdump` will process all that data on the group, bbut I'm just going to throw it away.

Note that because my specific environment, I have been discouraged from putting the interface in to promiscuous mode.  It may, in fact, be prohibited.

Comment: Unless you're running a non-standard version of tcpdump, you *are* putting the interface into promiscuous mode - the `-p` flag, in standard versions of tcpdump, turns promiscuous mode *off*, as it's *on* by default.  In promiscuous mode, it should see all traffic, including the multicast traffic, regardless of whether you have the subscription established - unless you're on a switched network and it's necessary to have the subscription established to have the switch forward you the traffic.

Comment: @GuyHarris:  Thanks for the clarification.  I am on a switched network.  Without the subscription already established (ie with `mdump` running in another console), `tcpdump` sees nothing.

Comment: And if they don't want you running in promiscuous mode, they probably also don't want you (or won't even *let* you) set up a "mirrored port" on the switch (assuming the switch even supports that) to get copies of all traffic through the switch (or all traffic through particular ports, if that's possible).

Comment: So what's wrong with doing this with a script?  What matters is whether it gets the job done, not whether somebody considers it "the usual way" - what's "unusual" about the script?

Comment: Promiscious mode is disabled because enabling it would, apparently, impact the other VMs on the host. This is undesired.  I *can* set up a mirrored port at the switch -- these are 40gb aristas -- but I'm not sure I see your point.

Comment: @GuyHarris:  Nothing is wrong with doing it in a script; I never said there was anything wrong with that.  What I said was using mdump to establish the joins felt un-standard to me.  When I searched for a way to just establish a join, and not process the inbound data in any way (which mdump does), I was surprised not to find an established method.  Perhaps `msump` or something like it *is* the established method.  But I'd rather not have a process reading and processing all that data if I'm just sending it to `/dev/null` -- that's wasteful.

Comment: I take it back somewhat.  Looking back I see how it *appears* that I'm saying doing everything in a script is bad.  But that's not what I meant.  Question edited.

Comment: Note these are two different things: promiscuous mode disables discarding packets which are received but not addressed to any listening address (including broadcast). joining a multicast address tells your network switches and/or routers to submit packets of the multicast group to your machine. This means: promicious mode without joining the multicast group will not dump the packet because it isn't sent to your network interface (in a well configured network). Normally, joining the group is enough for dumping.

Comment: @DanielAlder:  Right, and that's what's happening here.  I don't get any packets unless I join the multicast.  That I understand.  What I don't know is how best to join that multicast.

Comment: You can use the standard tool iproute2 on Linux to manage multicast addresses: `ip maddr show eth0` or `man 8 ip-maddress`. However this will only allow you to add or delete link layer addresses to or from a network interface. You would have to calculate the matching link layer address by yourself or write some script for that. I could not find a tool doing this.

Maybe see those other questions:

 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/17988757/462636
 - https://superuser.com/q/324824/254939

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TL;DR - Pick one:

`sudo ip addr add 233.54.12.234/32 dev eth1 autojoin`

`socat STDIO UDP4-RECV:22001,ip-add-membership=233.54.12.234:eth1 > /dev/null`

---

At first I was going to say "just use `ip maddress add` and be done with it". The problem is `ip maddress` only affects *link layer* multicast addresses not *protocol* multicast addresses ([`man 8 ip-maddress`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-maddress.8.html)).

That being said using the `autojoin` flag with the *address* verb does the trick just nicely.

This raises some subsequent questions though. I assume since you'll be running `tcpdump` or `tshark` that you have root permission.  *In the event that you do not* 22001 is a high numbered port and other utilities like `socat` will also get things done.

Don't take my word for it though.  Just to test this out we can generate multicast UDP packets with `socat` or `ncat` (generally packaged via `nmap`/`nmap-ncat`).

On some number of hosts run **one** of the following two combinations:

Option 1:

```
sudo ip addr add 233.54.12.234/32 dev eth1 autojoin
```

Option 2:

```
socat -u UDP4-RECV:22001,ip-add-membership=233.54.12.234:eth1 /dev/null &
```

The first option will require either root, or at least the [capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) `CAP_NET_ADMIN`.  The second option doesn't require root, but also expects to run in the foreground and thus *may* be less conducive to scripting (though tracking the child process ID and cleaning it up with a [`trap`](http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/) in BASH may be just what you're looking for.

Once that's done (but before we go nuts testing our `tcpdump`/`tshark` command) make sure that the kernel recognizes the interface having joined the correct IGMP group.  If you're feeling super fancy you can go nuts parsing the hex out of `/proc/net/igmp`, but I'd suggest just running `netstat -gn`.

Once you've verified that you see the interface subscribed to the correct group fire up your tcpdump command:

```
tcpdump -nnXs 0 -i eth1 udp port 22001 and dst 233.54.12.234
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to fully go the route of tcpdump (or stumbled upon this answer and are just curious to see multicast in action) you can use `socat` command above to join and echo the content to `STDOUT` by replacing `/dev/null` with `STDOUT`:

```
socat -u UDP4-RECV:22001,ip-add-membership=233.54.12.234:eth1
```

Then, from another machine use one of the following two options to send some simple test data:

Option 1:

```
socat STDIO UDP-DATAGRAM:233.54.12.234:22001
```

Option 2:

```
ncat  -u 233.54.12.234 22001
```

When you run either of those commands it will then interactively wait for input.  Just type some things in, hit enter to send, then `CTRL+D` when you're done to send an `EOF` message.

At this point you should have seen an end to end test and with a few commands built the worst, most insecure chat system in the world.

N.B.  If you want to leave the multicast group joined using `ip addr add ...` (option 1), you can do this:

```
sudo ip addr del 233.54.12.234/32 dev eth1 autojoin
```

Comment: Wow, it took 4 years to get an answer!  I'm not even doing this anymore, and really have no way to test, but I'll accept nonetheless.

Comment: Comes in handy just right now! :D Thanks Brian :)

Comment: I think the first solution needs a newer `ip` as I am getting `Error: either "local" is duplicate, or "autojoin" is a garbage.` on CentOS 7.  Second works.  Thanks.